# A function's access to variable environment, closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I know that functions have access to the variable environment (VE) of the execution context they were created in, but where are they carrying the reference to it, and is it possible to access it?

*edit*

Example:

```
function secureIncrement() {
    let counter = 0;

    return function () {
        counter++;
        console.log(`counter = ${counter}`);
    };
}

const incrementer = secureIncrement();
incrementer(); // 1
incrementer(); // 2
incrementer(); // 3
```

I know `incrementer` has access to the `counter` but within what property is it keeping a reference to it?

There is a `[[Scopes]]` property which can be seen with `console.dir(incrementer)`, but is it possible to access it manually?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: This is called a closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `incrementer` function object returned from `secureIncrement` has an internal slot called [`[[Environment]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#table-internal-slots-of-ecmascript-function-objects) set on it when it is created that points to the [environment record](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-environment-records) (ER) it's defined in. In your example, the function you return has its `[[Environment]]` slot set to `secureIncrement`'s ER which holds the binding for `counter`. The ER for  `secureIncrement` is obtained from its [execution context](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#table-additional-state-components-for-ecmascript-code-execution-contexts)'s lexical environment component (and not its variable environment component), which can be seen in [`InstantiateOrdinaryFunctionExpression`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateordinaryfunctionexpression) step 2. This then calls [`OrdinaryFunctionCreate`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ordinaryfunctioncreate) at step 4, which sets the `[[Environment]]` slot of the returned `incrementer` function to that ER at step 14.

When `incrementer()` is called, a [new function ER](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-function-environment-records) is created to store any bindings that might be created within its body (which in your example there are none). The new function ER also has its [`[[OuterEnv]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-environment-records) field set to the `[[Environment]]` of the `incrementer` function we just called, which can be seen in [`NewFunctionEnvironment`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-newfunctionenvironment) step 8. This means that when you refer to `counter` within the `increment` function, the `counter` binding is first searched for in the new ER that was created when you called `increment()`, and if it can't find the binding in there, it looks for it in the `[[OuterEnv]]` of the new ER. In your example, as the `counter` binding doesn't exist directly in the `increment` function scope (and hence its ER), the ER referenced by `[[OuterEnv]]` is also searched. Above we saw that this slot is set from the `[[Environment]]` slot, which we also saw references the scope / ER of the `secureIncrement` function. As a result, when the `[[OuterEnv]]` is checked for a `counter` binding, a binding can successfully be found. Resolving the `counter` identifier is done as part of the steps in [`GetIdentifierReference`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-getidentifierreference) that recursively searches an environment record by traveling up the scope chain through `[[OuterEnv]]` references.

There isn't an API that exposes these scopes, so you can't manually access them within your JavaScript code.

Answer (score -1):

Here the console will print 50 since t is scoped outside the function. The value passed to the console.log is a reference, which means when I update the original the value that will be printed changes as well.

```js
let t = 1;

setTimeout(() => console.log(t), 100);
t = 50
```

You can get access for example by providing an function wich returns the value or the object itself. Here `getCounter` will return the value of the counter.

```js
function secureIncrement() {
  let counter = 0;

  return {
    inc: function() {
      counter++;
      console.log(`counter = ${counter}`);
    },
    getCounter: () => counter
  };
}

const {
  inc,
  getCounter
} = secureIncrement();
inc(); // 1
console.log('myCounter: ', getCounter())
inc(); // 2
console.log('myCounter: ', getCounter())
inc(); // 3
console.log('myCounter: ', getCounter())
```

Comment: This shows an example of a closure, but does not answer the question. The question for your example would be, "how is the anonymous function storing a reference to `t`? Where in memory Is the reference being kept? Is the reference available on the function prototype? If so, how can I access it?".